# Search and Pagination not working while using server-side

Tags: php, jquery, datatables, pagination, server-side

I am using the data table server-side. I am getting the records using ajax. My issue is, search and pagination not working. I am getting the search and pagination along with all the data.

Please check the below image, I am showing 10 records per page but it is showing all.

[image]

I checked on StackOverflow there are server question asked on this topic. I almost checked every question but still, I am not able to find the solution.

I am using below code

```
if($_REQUEST['action']=='adminList'){

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM tbl_admin");
$stmt->execute();
$totalRecords = $stmt->fetchColumn();
$query="SELECT `admin_id`, `a_firstname`, `a_lastname`, `a_email`,  `date_of_created` FROM `tbl_admin` WHERE is_active = 1 order by date_of_created DESC";

try {
      $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
      $stmt->execute();
      $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
             
      $data['data'] = [];
      foreach ($result as $row) {

        $arr_result = array(
                    //"id" =>$i++,
                    "name" =>$row['a_firstname'].' '.$row['a_lastname'],
                    "email" => $row['a_email'],
                    "date_of_created" => $row['date_of_created'],
        );


        $data['data'][] = $arr_result;
                }

                
                }
                catch(PDOException $e) {
                    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
                }

$json_data = array(  
"draw"=> intval( $_REQUEST['draw'] ),
"recordsTotal"    => intval($totalRecords),  
"recordsFiltered" => intval($totalRecords),
"data"            => $data['data']
);

// echo "<pre>";
 //print_r($json_data);
echo json_encode($json_data);
//exit();
}
```

Js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dataTable = $('#adminList').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "paging": true,
    "searchable": true,
    "ajax": {
      url: "fetch.php",
      type: "post",
      data: {
        action: "adminList"
      }
    },
    language: {
      sLengthMenu: "Show _MENU_", // remove entries text
      searchPlaceholder: "Search",
      emptyTable: "No record found",
      search: ""
    },
    "pageLength": 10,
    "paging": true,
    "columns": [{
        "data": "name"
      },
      {
        "data": "email"
      },
      {
        "data": "date_of_created"
      }
    ]
  });
});
```

This is my output

```
Array
(
    [draw] => 1
    [recordsTotal] => 17
    [recordsFiltered] => 17
    [data] => Array
        (
    // getting my all records
)
)
```

Can anyone help me out what is the issue with my code?

Comment: There is some (old) sample code on https://legacy.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html.  For paging look at `if ( isset( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' )` as your code always fetches all of the data (not LIMIT in your SQL)

Comment: @NigelRen, But where I have to add that code? I believe that coming from the data table plugin.

Comment: @NigelRen, If I use LIMIT in my query then I will get only limited value..right? I have to show all the records and I have to display 10 records per page

Comment: LIMIT allows you to say which set of records to return - have a look at [Pagination using MySQL LIMIT, OFFSET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20364349/pagination-using-mysql-limit-offset)

Comment: @NigelRen, I set LIMIT 10 in my query. So now I am getting only 10 records but what about other records? I believe that the data table handles all this type of limit.

Comment: Check the serveside code of datatable here and implement it accordingly: https://github.com/pandeyz/Jquery-Datatable-Server-Side-with-Custom-Inline-Editing

Comment: @MayankPandeyz, Can you check my code once? My pagination is working but I am getting all the records.

Answer (score 0):

#### PROBLEM

You have enabled server-side processing mode with `serverSide: true` which requires you to handle searching, ordering and pagination performed on the server-side by your script. However your script returns all the data, that's why you see all results and not just first page.

#### SOLUTION

1. Write proper server-side handling code or use helper libraries.

   For example, DataTables distribution includes [ssp.class.php](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php) helper calss and [sample script](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/server_processing.php) to aid in generating response if you're using PHP.

   Otherwise, you can inspect [sent parameters](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Sent-parameters) and paginate your results based on `start` and `length` request parameters.
2. Switch to client-side processing mode by removing `serverSide: true` as your initialization option and return all data in your server-side response. Please keep in mind that this solution is not ideal if you have a large dataset (>10,000 records).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Let me implement this

Comment: Regarding ssp.class.php. One month  ago I asked on the question  but I haven't got solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62708059/datatables-server-side-processing-not-displaying-the-output-on-page-and-where-co

Comment: I tried  lengthMenu:[[3,25,50,100,-1],[3,25,50,100,"All"]], "pageLength":3,but still my all records are displaying.

Comment: I removed all the code and refer this link https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html. Now I am getting the output.  But I this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63426594/where-clause-not-working-in-data-table-server-side-processing